# Created a Page as LoadingIndicator in Xamarin.forms?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my application I have created my own Loading indicator with the help of Page class in xamarin.forms, and I use 'PushModalAsync' api to show Loading Indicator wherever needed like below

```
var loadingindicator=new LoadingIndicator();
MyApp.CurrentAppInstance.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(loadingindicator,false);
```

Everything works as expected and It is looking fine and I also managed to make it look like AndHUD by tweeking the alpha for the controls in that page until I hit an issue,

The issue is that,  every time I show and hide the loadingindicator page 'OnAppearing()' getting called on the current top page on view stack.

I can fix this by introducing one additional functionality on all pages where I am using my LoadingIndicator, But I feel there might be some other cleaner way to solve this issue.

Can you guys suggest me if there is any cleaner approach available to solve this issue?

(I target this solution mainly for android and I want to achieve it through common code)

Comment: The problem you are describing is intended behavior from Xamarin.Forms.  You pop a Modal, OnDisappearing() is called on the page as it goes behind the modal.  When you hide the modal, it disappears and the top page reappears, which means OnAppearing() will be called.

My question would by why is it a problem?

Comment: @Adam Nolan theoretically that should not be a problem, I just want to know if any way I can suppress that behaviour as I don't want to handle the LoadingIndicator page show and hide triggering  'OnAppearing' method.

Answer (score 3):

If I have understand the problem, I think there are some way to add Loading indicator.

1. Use [ActivityIndicator](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ActivityIndicator/)
2. Use [aritchie/userdialogs](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs)'s Loading

   ```
               using (this.Dialogs.Loading("Test Loading"))
                   await Task.Delay(3000);
   ```
3. Create a PopUp With [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup)

   // Use these methods in PopupNavigation globally or Navigation in your pages

   // Open new PopupPage
   Task PushAsync(PopupPage page, bool animate = true) // Navigation.PushPopupAsync

   // Hide last PopupPage
   Task PopAsync(bool animate = true) // Navigation.PopPopupAsync

   // Hide all PopupPage with animations
   Task PopAllAsync(bool animate = true) // Navigation.PopAllPopupAsync

   // Remove one popup page in stack
   Task RemovePageAsync(PopupPage page, bool animate = true) // Navigation.RemovePopupPageAsync

Comment: we are facing some issues with AndHUD like this https://github.com/Redth/AndHUD/issues/34

Comment: with aritchie's lib?